# See my own Ethernet Raw Connection with wireshark and python

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet, loopback

I tried to send a message under the Ethernet protocol profinet than I don't know how to continue. I want to send a msg to my own computer with ethernet and I want to check the message exchange with Wireshark, but i cannot see any information about my communication. Where is my fault or what am I missing? Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
from socket import *
from fcntl import ioctl


import fcntl, struct



s=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)

s.bind(("enp2s0",0))



def get_mac(ifname):
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    info = ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927, struct.pack('256s', bytes(ifname[:15], "ascii")))
    return info[18:24]

src = get_mac("enp2s0")
print(src)

src_addr = "\xb8\xec\xa3\x80\xeb\xb4"
payload = ("["*30)+"MESSAGE"+("]"*30)
checksum = "\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d"
ethertype = "\x88\x92" #0x8892 profinet protocole




print((src_addr+src_addr+ethertype+payload+checksum).encode('utf-8'))

s.send((src_addr+src_addr+ethertype+payload+checksum).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: 'I fail' is not an accurate description of the problem you encountered. Without a clear description of what doesn't work as you expected,  we can't help you.

Comment: I added details

Comment: do you have a logfile or some kind of output from your program?

Comment: No but i dont know that is true way or false. Actually how can i communicate under the ethernet profinet ?

Comment: You probably want `s.sendto(package, (dest_ip , 0 ))` and if you're using Python3, you should build your packet using `src_addr = b"\xb8\xec\xa3\x80\xeb\xb4"` instead. Because that's what the socket layer wants, bytes data.

Comment: You also have to make sure that the interface is up before you send your data. And that iptables/fw isn't blocking any traffic or malformed packets. Probably not in your case, but most of the time the kernel will drop packets pretty early on (some times even on hardware level outside of the kernel) and then you're screwed.. So make sure your interface is in promiscuous mode when sniffing and better even if you can have a separate machine with that configuration sniffing the network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code must be run with administrator privileges (sudo or su on linux). Then by running your code there's an error with this traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eth.py", line 15, in <module>
    src = get_mac("enp2s0")
  File "eth.py", line 12, in get_mac
    info = ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927, struct.pack('256s', bytes(ifname[:15], "ascii")))
  TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

which founds out that there's an error on line 12, more precisely on `bytes(ifname[:15],"ascii")`
Can you provide your output?